# Get node content from xml file and transform it into php array?

Tags: php, arrays, xmlstarlet

I'm looking for solution to extract some node from large xml file (using **xmlstarlet** http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) and then parse this node to **php array**.

```
elements.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<elements>
  <element id="1" par1="val1_1" par2="val1_2" par3="val1_3">
    <title>element 1 title</title>
    <description>element 1 description</description>
  </element>
  <element id="2" par1="val2_1" par2="val2_2" par3="val2_3">
    <title>element 2 title</title>
    <description>element 2 description</description>
  </element>
</elements>
```

To extract *element tag with id="1"* using **xmlstarlet** I'm executing this shell command...

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/elements/element[id=1]" elements.xml
```

This shell command outputs something like this...

```
<element id="1" par1="val1_1" par2="val1_2" par3="val1_3">
  <title>element 1 title</title>
  <description>element 1 description</description>
</element>
```

How could I parse this shell output into **php array**?

Thank you.

---

I've found http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php pretty useful. This SimpleXML function will convert extracted piece of XML to SimpleXML object.

Comment: just curious, why use xmlstar over something like simplexml or the xml dom?

Comment: My XML file is pretty large (~100Mb). I'm not sure that Simplexml or XmlDom do not load whole xml file into RAM (this could cause php memory overusage); but I'm not sure saying it because I know nothing about Simplexml mechanism of parsing XML files.

Comment: SimpleXML and DOM do pretty much the same, since they use the same implementation of libxml. The functions to switch between dom and simplexml do little more than just handing over their internal xmlNodePtr. So yes, the document would be in memory. But there are other parsers extensions like e.g. XMLReader.

Comment: How would you execute that xmlstarlet+php combination? Is it a php script that calls xmlstarlet (e.g. via exec()?) Or do you start from the commandline like `xmlstarlet params parmas params | php -f params` ?

Comment: @VolkerK, I'm just using shell_exec() to call xmlstarlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always take the new outputted xml and use simplexml like:

```
$data = '<element id="1" par1="val1_1" par2="val1_2" par3="val1_3">
<title>element 1 title</title>
<description>element 1 description</description>
</element>';


$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
echo $xml->title; //access title
echo $element_ID = $xml->attributes()->id; //access elements attributes by name
```

and now `$xml` is the array you need